# How can I set the javascript path in my JSP to display date

Tags: javascript, jsp, jquery-ui-datepicker

My web application structure is shown like below.

```
tomcat
|--webapps
  |-- META-INF
  |-- WEB-INF
    |-- css
    |--js
    |-- jsp
    |    |-- index.jsp
    |--web.xml
```

aa
I set the JavaScript path in the index.jsp like following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
    </body>
</html>
```

I put all js file under the js folder

But it could not load the JavaScript file
It display only Date text in JSP page
How to I display the date picker in index.jsp page?
Please help me...

Comment: You haven't included the date picker library.

Answer (score 0):

Move the < in front of "Date:" to the front of "input".  Then when you click on the text field  you get the date picker.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 <script>
 $(function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
 });
</script>
</head>
   <body>

    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
  </body>
 </html>
```

i copy pasted this code and made an html file clicked on text field and date picker worked .One of the reason can be internet is not working on your system.Check the internet

[image: for understanding the structure]

for more information about structure see the following link

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19146-01/821-1830/abxft/index.html

Comment: And you didn't mention that you moved the angle bracket from "Date:" to "input."  Which I already mentioned.

Comment: @user1329482  thnx for mentioning this

Comment: IS it possible to load the date picker with out internet. I load all js file in my js folder.

Comment: @user3048296  use the path of the place where you have stored all the js files

Comment: I place my js file in WEB-INF-->js-->js files and i set path like <script src="..js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="..js/jquery-ui.js"></script> But it is not working. is it correct? how to set the path?

Comment: why are u placing the files in the `WEB-INF` folder the folder in which `WEB-INF` resides u can give the relative path to that .In that directory make two `dir` `js` and `css` put their files in the corresponding directories and give your path like `js/jquery-1.9.1.js` `js/jquery-ui.js` `css/jquery-ui.css` this will work .I have checked this.For your case it will webapps make the js and css directory in to that put files and give the path like i have mentioned

Comment: @user3048296 i have added the project structure and running application instance check that the path in my jsp file given is same like i have mentioned in the above comment

Comment: @user3048296  if your problem solved please accept the answer